# Downloading thousands of files using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib2, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to download about 500k small csv files (5kb-1mb) from a list of urls but it is been taking too long to get this done. With the code bellow, I am lucky if I get 10k files a day.

I have tried using the multiprocessing package and a pool to download multiple files simultaneously. This seems to be effective for the first few thousand downloads, but eventually the overall speed goes down. I am no expert, but I assume that the decreasing speed indicates that the server I am trying to download from cannot keep up with this number of requests. Does that makes sense?

To be honest, I am quite lost here and was wondering if there is any piece of advice on how to speed this up.

```
import urllib2
import pandas as pd
import csv
from multiprocessing import Pool

#import url file
df = pd.read_csv("url_list.csv")

#select only part of the total list to download 
list=pd.Series(df[0:10000])


#define a job and set file name as the id string under urls
def job(url):
    file_name = str("test/"+url[46:61])+".csv"
    u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    f = open(file_name, 'wb')
    f.write(u.read())
    f.close()

#run job
pool = Pool()
url = [ "http://" + str(file_path) for file_path in list]
pool.map(job, url)
```

Comment: you can write all urls in a text file, then use a download manager like `aria2` to download them :-)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I think it might work well. I've been reading the aria2 documentation and can't find how to name the files. do you know if it is possible to name the downloaded files with the url (or a substring of it)?

Comment: `aria2c -i file.txt`

Comment: exactly, it works perfectly. but all my files are downloaded with the same name and aria2 overrides that adding a number to each of them. however, I need them to be named after the url that was used to download them. there is the -o option, but it does not seem to be applicable when downloading from an input file.

Comment: i have the solution now: file names should be in the txt file separated by a space or tab.

Answer (score -1):

You are re-coding the wheel!

How about that :

```
parallel -a urls.file axel
```

Of course you'll have to install `parallel` and `axel` for your distribution.

`axel` is a multithreaded counterpart to `wget`

`parrallel` allows you to run tasks using multithreading.

Comment: thank you for the comment. it works fine too, but i am still struggling to name the files correctly. this is paramount since the csv do not carry any information regarding their original url.